# RelativeLayout, how to align center of other view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I created these views

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/opaque_red" />
<View
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/a"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/a"
    android:background="@color/opaque_red" />
<View
    android:id="@+id/c"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/a"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/a"
    android:background="@color/opaque_red" />
```

How can I align to this?

[image]

I cannot use another layout to wrap these three views, because I will use `OnTouchListener` to move `a` view, the position calculation will base on `a`. If wrap in other layout, calculation is very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

align b and c to the bottom or top of a, and then add either 15dp marin to the bottom or top of b and c respectively. Because your views have a hardcoded size, this works.

basically

```
margin = ((a.height - b.height) / 2)
```

Another way would have to been contain them in a relative layout set to wrap_content or the height of a, and align b and c to the vertical center, but you said you don't want that.

Comment: Actually that is three wrap_content ImageView without size, I just hardcoded size for the question

Comment: regardless of size, the algorithm holds. Also regardless, if you wrap them in a layout it will make it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Set height of parent layout to wrap_content, then put children to centre:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/a"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/c"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/a"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]